# AttributeError: 'Serializer' object has no attribute 'Meta' in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am using serializers.Serializer instead of ModelSerializer which doesn't require Meta class but it keep saying object has no attribute Meta. Iam not sure what is the issue but when I run the localserver, the main page gives error saying api fetch error and in the terminal it says  AttributeError: 'Serializer' object has no attribute 'Meta'.

My view:

```
class ClassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Class.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'get_all_students_of_a_class': ClassDetailSerializer,
    }
    # .annotate(total_students=Count('students_in_class'))
    def get_serializer_class(self):

        """
            returns a serializer class based on the action
            that has been defined.
        """
        try:
            return self.serializer_action_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return super(ClassView, self).get_serializer_class()

   
    def get_all_students_of_a_class(self,request,pk=None):

        """
            returns a class details with all the students signed up for the
            class along with the subject.
        """

        id = pk
        if self.is_teacher(id):
            online_classes = get_object_or_404(Class, id=id)
            students = Student.objects.filter(online_class__id=id)
            subject_details = Subject.objects.get(online_class__id=id)
            total_students_in_class = online_classes.total_students_in_class
            created_at = online_classes.created_at
            updated_at = online_classes.updated_at
            data = {
                "teacher": self.get_teacher_instance(),
                'total_students_in_class': total_students_in_class,
                "students_in_class": students,
                "subject": subject_details,
                'created_at': created_at,
                'last_updated_at': updated_at,

            }
            serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
            serializer = serializer_class(data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My serializer:

```
class ClassDetailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    teacher = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    subject = SubjectLevelSerializer()
    total_students_in_class = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    students_in_class = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    last_updated_at =  serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

My url:

```
 path("class/<int:pk>/",teacher.ClassView.as_view({"get": "get_all_students_of_a_class","delete":"destroy"}),
    ),
```

However it works and I can perform action if I go to localhost/admin and other api calls from localhost.

Comment: does your serializer have a meta class?

Comment: No it doesnt have meta class .

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre]. Please share the _full_ error traceback, also what specific action do you make a request to?

Comment: I made the request to `def get_details_of_employee(self,request,pk=None):`  from the url router

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Hello I have made some changes into the codes and posted full code here along with the traceback. @BrianDestura &Abdul

Comment: Haven't used `drf-spectacular` before but based on the traceback it seems it requires your serializer to have `Meta` (like `ModelSerializer`) since it uses the model in `follow_field_source`

Comment: what is follow  field source??

Comment: It's from the traceback you shared -- `target = follow_field_source(field.parent.Meta.model, field.source_attrs)`

Comment: But it is normal serailizers.Serialzer which should not be expecting meta class

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat can you make something from the traceback??

Answer (score 0):

Add a Meta class with `model = YourModel`

```
class ExampleDetailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    employee = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    person = PersonSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Example # model name
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: Since it is not Modelserializer we do we need meta class with meta?? It is a simple serializer class according to the drf documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, BTW does this solve your issue? I think the the ModelViewset needs Meta class in its serializer..

Comment: @Django-Rocks did this worked for you, if you found any other solution feel free to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "ViewSet" instead of "ModelViewSet". And while using ViewSet make sure to define list, create, etc. function by your own.